# Restart application programmatically

Tags: macos, swift

I would like to know if is any method to restart my app programmatically. 
It's a mac os app and I work with Xcode 6 in swift.

The procedure is simple, at a given time I want to restart my app. I guess I need a simple Helper  but i'm not sure.

Comment: You could find then use the Swift wrapper for the POSIX [exec*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) functions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you need helper tool. here is the procedure:

1. Create helper "Command Line Tool" target in your Project. For example, named "**relaunch**"

   **relaunch/main.swift**:

   ```
   import AppKit

   // KVO helper
   class Observer: NSObject {

       let _callback: () -> Void

       init(callback: () -> Void) {
           _callback = callback
       }

       override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
           _callback()
       }
   }


   // main
   autoreleasepool {

       // the application pid
       let parentPID = atoi(C_ARGV[1])

       // get the application instance
       if let app = NSRunningApplication(processIdentifier: parentPID) {

           // application URL
           let bundleURL = app.bundleURL!

           // terminate() and wait terminated.
           let listener = Observer { CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()) }
           app.addObserver(listener, forKeyPath: "isTerminated", options: nil, context: nil)
           app.terminate()
           CFRunLoopRun() // wait KVO notification
           app.removeObserver(listener, forKeyPath: "isTerminated", context: nil)

           // relaunch
           NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().launchApplicationAtURL(bundleURL, options: nil, configuration: [:], error: nil)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add `Products/relaunch` binary to "Copy Bundle Resources" in the main application target.
3. Add `relaunch` target to "Target Dependencies" in the main application target.

   [image: screenshot]
4. Add `relaunch` function in the main application.

   For example: **NSApplication+Relaunch.swift**:

   ```
   extension NSApplication {
       func relaunch(sender: AnyObject?) {
           let task = NSTask()
           // helper tool path
           task.launchPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("relaunch", ofType: nil)!
           // self PID as a argument
           task.arguments = [String(NSProcessInfo.processInfo().processIdentifier)]
           task.launch()
       }
   }
   ```

Then, call `NSApplication.sharedApplication().relaunch(nil)` as you like.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I was unable to terminate the app within the relaunch tool with `app.terminate()`. It was denied by the ** sandbox **. Console.app output: `AppleEvents/sandbox: Returning errAEPrivilegeError/-10004 and denying dispatch of event aevt/quit from process ''/0x0-0x0, pid=28376, because it is not entitled to send an AppleEvent to this process.` I ended up terminating the app in the NSApplication extension after launching the relaunch tool. `NSApp.terminate(nil)`

Comment: is it works for sandboxed apps?

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3 version, based on Rintaro’s code and Cenox Kang’s workaround.
See Rintaro’s answer for instructions.

**relaunch/main.swift:**

```
import AppKit

// KVO helper
class Observer: NSObject {

    let _callback: () -> Void

    init(callback: @escaping () -> Void) {
        _callback = callback
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                      of object: Any?,
                      change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                      context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        _callback()
    }
}


// main
autoreleasepool {

    // the application pid
    guard let parentPID = Int32(CommandLine.arguments[1]) else {
        fatalError("Relaunch: parentPID == nil.")
    }

    // get the application instance
    if let app = NSRunningApplication(processIdentifier: parentPID) {

        // application URL
        let bundleURL = app.bundleURL!

        // terminate() and wait terminated.
        let listener = Observer { CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()) }
        app.addObserver(listener, forKeyPath: "isTerminated", context: nil)
        app.terminate()
        CFRunLoopRun() // wait KVO notification
        app.removeObserver(listener, forKeyPath: "isTerminated", context: nil)

        // relaunch
        do {
            try NSWorkspace.shared().launchApplication(at: bundleURL, configuration: [:])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Relaunch: NSWorkspace.shared().launchApplication failed.")
        }
    }
}
```

**NSApplication+Relaunch.swift:**

```
import AppKit

extension NSApplication {
    func relaunch(sender: AnyObject?) {
        let task = Process()
        // helper tool path
        task.launchPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "relaunch", ofType: nil)!
        // self PID as a argument
        task.arguments = [String(ProcessInfo.processInfo.processIdentifier)]
        task.launch()
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I was unable to terminate the app within the relaunch tool with `app.terminate()`. It was denied by the ** sandbox **. Console.app output: `AppleEvents/sandbox: Returning errAEPrivilegeError/-10004 and denying dispatch of event aevt/quit from process ''/0x0-0x0, pid=28376, because it is not entitled to send an AppleEvent to this process.` I ended up terminating the app in the NSApplication extension after launching the relaunch tool. `NSApp.terminate(nil)`

Comment: is it works for sandboxed apps?

Answer (score 4):

**swift4 function**

```
@objc private func buttonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
    if let path = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString {
        NSLog("restart \(path)")
        _ = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/usr/bin/open", arguments: [path])
        NSApp.terminate(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should explain yourself a little better!

Comment: is it works for sandboxed apps?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you wenyou , i just simplified :

```
func restart()
{
  Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/usr/bin/open", arguments: ["-b", Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!])
  NSApp.terminate(self)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://gist.github.com/BenLeggiero/449fb9b1a45b69fb276f4f9ad86cab7a

worked for me

```
func relaunch(afterDelay seconds: TimeInterval = 0.5) -> Never {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    task.arguments = ["-c", "sleep \(seconds); open \"\(Bundle.main.bundlePath)\""]
    task.launch()
    
    NSApp.terminate(self)
    exit(0)
}
```

Comment: is it works for sandboxed apps?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround rintaro's code in Swift 2.

```
// the application pid
let parentPID = atoi(C_ARGV[1])
```

to

```
// the application pid
let parentPID = Int32(Process.arguments[1])
```

It works to me.