# After Update, app is not getting restarted cocoa objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, pkg-file, app-update

I am trying to update the mac app which is distributed outside app store  so followed the process as suggested [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110810) 
After downloading the .pkg file i am opening the using `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:filePath.path];` but after successfully installed app is not getting opened so what do i need to do so that after app update i want app to restart

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://macappsupdate/localapp.pkg"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {

        NSLog(@"downloading in progress %@",downloadProgress);

    } destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        NSLog(@"documentsDirectoryURL %@",documentsDirectoryURL);
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];

    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
        NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert new];
        alert.messageText = @"You are currently using an old version of the app.\nTo enjoy the latest features please Upgrade!";
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Update"];

        NSModalResponse response1 = [alert runModal];
        if(response1 == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:filePath.path];
            [NSApp terminate:nil];

        }


    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
```

Any Suggestions ?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: It is Swift. But perhaps it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479801/restart-application-programmatically

Comment: @ivion how to trigger that app update is completed successfully so that i can relaunch.

Comment: Look at projects Sparkle or Squirrel. They have been the norm for updating apps and they can handle relaunch.